# Kick/Ban Command´s Discord.js v12 With a reason

Tags: discord.js

Good morning, I would like to know how I could do a kick and ban command, but that I can add a reason and that only specific members can use it. Currently I have this code, but I do not know how to do to set permissions and that I can give a reason.

```
client.on('message', message => {



  if (!message.guild) return;


  if (message.content.startsWith('kick')) {
    
            


    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // If we have a user mentioned
    if (user) {

      const member = message.guild.member(user);

      if (member) {

        member
          .kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
          .then(() => {

            message.reply(`Has kickeado a: ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {

            message.reply('No he podido kickear a el miembro.');

            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {

        message.reply("El jugador no está en el Guild!");
      }

    } else {
      message.reply("Pero hombre, mencioname al pobrecito que vas a kickear...");
    }
  }
   
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.guild) return;

            

  if (message.content.startsWith('ban')) {

    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    
    if (user) {

      const member = message.guild.member(user);

      if (member) {
        

        member
          .ban('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
          .then(() => {

            message.reply(`Has baneado a: ${user.tag}`);
             message.author.send('Has sido baneado por mal comportamiento!')
          })

          .catch(err => {

            message.reply('No he podido banear al usuario.');

            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {

        message.reply("El jugador no está en el Guild!");
      }

    } else {
      message.reply("Pero hombre, mencioname al pobrecito que vas a banear");
    }
  
}
})
});
```

As you can see, it is a command that everyone can access, and that along with the reason for the ban, I would like to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check member's permission with [GuildMember#hasPermission](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission)

For example:

```
 if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") return;
```

Here is a list of permissions: [Permissions#FLAGS](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS)

Comment: And how i can provide a reason?

Comment: You can add reason by doing this: .kick("reason here")